# keras ImageDataGenetor: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I am working on this dataset:
[British Birdsong dataset](http://%20https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/british-birdsong-dataset)

with this approach: [Toward Data Science Article](https://towardsdatascience.com/sound-based-bird-classification-965d0ecacb2b)

However, I get this following error:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

My code is the following:

''

```
# Plot mel-spectrogram
N_FFT = 1024         
HOP_SIZE = 1024       
N_MELS = 128            
WIN_SIZE = 1024      
WINDOW_TYPE = 'hann' 
FEATURE = 'mel'      
FMIN = 1400 

spectrogram = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y = x[2],sr = samplerate[2], n_fft = N_FFT, hop_length = HOP_SIZE, n_mels = N_MELS, htk = True, fmin = FMIN, fmax = samplerate[2]/2) 

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
librosa.display.specshow(librosa.power_to_db(spectrogram**2,ref=np.max), fmin=FMIN,y_axis='linear')
plt.colorbar(format='%+2.0f dB')
plt.show()

image_size = (224,224,3) 
birds_names = dataset.iloc[:, 3].unique()
path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/701_data"
batch_size = 16

train_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range = 0.2, height_shift_range = 0.2, shear_range = 0.2, zoom_range = 0.1, fill_mode = 'nearest')
train_batches = train_data_generator.flow_from_directory(path + 'train', classes = birds_names, target_size = image_size, class_mode = 'categorical', shuffle = True, batch_size = batch_size)

test_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function = preprocess_input)
test_batches = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(path + 'test', classes = birds_names, target_size = image_size, class_mode = 'categorical', shuffle = False, batch_size = batch_size)
''
```

[code's ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAkwb.png)

I would really be grateful if you could help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome! It would help people who answer your question if you send code that could be copied in a code block or other source.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried to do it. However, I didn't know how can I do it. Please, help me to do it @FluxedScript

Comment: You can use ```python some code here`` or use a site like https://pastebin.com/

Comment: But there are only for jquery, html,... so forth... @FluxedScript

Comment: Done! @FluxedScript

Comment: Please include the full traceback of the error in your question as well.

Comment: can you try : `birds_names = dataset.iloc[:, 3].unique().to_numpy()`